# Cannot find module '@app/common' in e2e tests for NestJS microservices

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I make a NestJS project with 2 microservice and a common library, structured in the following way:

```
- apps
    - auth
    - profile
       - src
           - profile.service.ts
       - test
           - app.e2e-spec.ts
- libs/common
    - index.ts
    - tsconfig.lib.json
```

ProfileService (profile.service.ts) imports from library (from '@app/common').
When I run the profile app - all worked as expected.

But when I run the e2e test for the profile app - it crashes

```bash
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module '@app/common' from '../src/profile.service.ts'
```

How can I fix this? Since it is an e2e test it seems a bad idea to mock ProfileService

Comment: Did you set up the [`moduleNameMapper`](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#modulenamemapper-objectstring-string--arraystring) option in your `jest.e2e-config.json`?

Comment: did you find any solution ? if yes please share

Comment: I added code snippet

Answer (score 2):

As Jay McDoniel pointed out in first comment, error was due to file **jest-e2e.json**.

NestJs automaticly generate "moduleNameMapper" in package.json file, but not in  jest-e2e.json file. And e2e test also need "moduleNameMapper" in jest-e2e.json

So, for the monorepo app

```
 - apps
    - auth
    - profile
       - test
           - app.e2e-spec.ts  # this test cannot find module
           - jest-e2e.json    # need to add moduleMapper here to fix

 - libs
   - first
   - second
```

Such  "moduleNameMapper" will fix the error for any lib

```
{
  "moduleFileExtensions": ["js", "json", "ts"],
  "rootDir": ".",
  "testEnvironment": "node",
  "testRegex": ".e2e-spec.ts$",
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
  },
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "@app/([^/]*)/(.*)": "<rootDir>../../../libs/$1/src/$2",
    "@app/(.*)": "<rootDir>../../../libs/$1/src"
  }
}
```

Here $1 is a library name and $2 is path in this library

Comment: Спасибо, Игорь!